# How to get a list of EVault Plugins using SoftLayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What SoftLayer API do I use to get a list of an EVault Plugin that I have?
It can be all of the EVault plugins that I have or it can be all the Plugins that are associated with a particular EVault or with a particular host.

I need to get a list which contains details of each
or get a list then find a way to get details of each from the list.

Maybe I missed, but I didn't see any helpful API from SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault or didn't see any SoftLayer service APIs which contains the word "plugin".

Answer (score 0):

You can use “SoftLayer_Product_Package::getCategories” to get Evault plugin items.

Reference:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getCategories

For example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getCategories?objectMask=mask[id,categoryCode,groups[prices[id,item]]]

Method: GET

Where: 
The package used for Evault is 0
The “categoryCode” that we are interested in: "categoryCode": "evault_plugin"
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{
"categoryCode": "evault_plugin"
"id": 57
"groups": [1]
0:  {
"itemCategoryId": 57
"packageId": 0
"sort": 0
"prices": [30]
0:  {
"id": 11111
"item": {
"description": "EVault Plugin - Sharepoint"
"id": 111
"itemTaxCategoryId": 166
"keyName": "EVAULT_PLUGIN_SHAREPOINT"
"softwareDescriptionId": 175
"upgradeItemId": null
}-
}-
1:  {
"id": 22222
"item": {
"description": "EVault Plugin - Oracle"
"id": 222
"itemTaxCategoryId": 166
"keyName": "EVAULT_PLUGIN_ORACLE"
"softwareDescriptionId": 177
"upgradeItemId": null
}-
}-
2:  {
"id": 33333
"item": {
"description": "EVault Plugin - Open TXN Manager"
"id": 333
"itemTaxCategoryId": 166
"keyName": "EVAULT_PLUGIN_OPEN_TXN_MANAGER"
"softwareDescriptionId": 176
"upgradeItemId": null
}-
}
….
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php

require_once ('/SoapClient.class.php');

$username = 'set me';
$key = 'set me';

$accountClient = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Account', null, $username, $key);

$objectMask = new SoftLayer_ObjectMask();
$objectMask->evaultNetworkStorage->pluginBillingItems;
$objectMask->evaultNetworkStorage->pluginBillingItems->item;
$accountClient->setObjectMask($objectMask);

# Getting the billing items
$result = $accountClient->getEvaultNetworkStorage();

print_r($result);
```